# Normals along a Sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth 2-manifold that is homeomorphic to a sphere or a connected sum or tori. Does there always exists two points $x,y \in M$ such that the normals $\angle(n_x, n_y) \geq 90^{\circ}$? It seems intuitively obvious but how does one formally prove this?

Comment: This looks like a DG homework assignment.

Comment: It's not, self study.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $M\subset \Bbb R^3$ and that is how you are measuring angles. Consider the map for each $x\in M$,  $\phi_x:  \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ which moves along the normal at $x$. By the tranversality theorem, $\phi_x \pitchfork M$ for almost every $x\in M$. For all $x$, $|\phi_x(\Bbb R)\cap M| \geq 2$, so now you can just look at an intersection point adjacent to the one at $x$ (with no intersection points in between).

Comment: Actually I intended for $M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, codimension $\geq 1$,  but I think pointing me toward the transversality theorem should be enough. Thanks!